# output odd numbers without if

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to output only odd numbers from this program:

```
m = int(input())
n = int(input())
for i in range(m, n - 1, -1,):
    print(i)
```

pls without if

Comment: What is your question? Expected output vs actual output?

Answer (score 3):

Using `and` instead of `if`:

```
i&1 and print(i)
```

(Better use range with step -2, I just dislike such restriction questions and always try to work around the restrictions in unintended ways).

Comment: This actually in a for-range loop prints 0 instead of the even numbers. Anyway that's a short and smart solution (I didn't know about the use of and syntax this way) +1

Comment: @FLAK-ZOSO Maybe if you execute that in a repl shell or whatever that's called. If you run it normally as a program, there's no such extra printing.

Comment: I used the Python shell with version 3.10.1 (https://ibb.co/88LRmFC)

Comment: @FLAK-ZOSO Yeah yeah, that's what I meant. So just don't do that :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a striding range as long as you make sur to adjust the starting number:

```
m = int(input())
n = int(input())
for i in range(m+1-m%2,n+1,2): # start at next odd if m is even
    print(i)
```

If you want them in decreasing order:

```
m = int(input())
n = int(input())
for i in reversed(range(m+1-m%2,n+1,2)):
    print(i)
```

Comment: But op wants to "output only odd numbers".

Comment: Thank you this is the most understandable way to solve, especially for a beginner

Comment: This is probably the best solution since you don't care about the first number if it's even.

Comment: I'd use `m|1` instead of `m+1-m%2`.

Comment: @Kelly,  very nice.  But would warrant some explaining for beginners: setting a number's low order bit to 1 makes it odd (increments by 1) if it is even or keeps it as is if it is already odd

Answer (score 1):

Without a guarantee that your start value is odd it becomes a little more tricky since you cannot simply step by 2. You can still get away with it(slightly) using conditionals like so:

```
m = int(input())
n = int(input())
for i in range(m, n):
    output_str = (f"{str(i % 2)}" or "") * i
    output_str += (i % 2) * '\n'
    print(output, end="")
```

I should put a disclaimer here that I'm strictly answering the question. I do not exactly endorse this method.

Comment: thanks for this decision

Comment: I agree with you, there's no way to endorse a method to sobstitute a one-line if statement...    Anyway I would have never thought to a solution like this, +1

Comment: Yes, I know it's very difficult, especially for me, but I'm interested in this way of solving this problem.

Comment: You forgot to initialize the `output` variable.

Comment: @martineau good catch, thanks. Missed that when making an edit.

Comment: Since you're talking about an increasing range... I'd say starting with `m | 1` instead of `m` is not particulately tricky...